# AWS Amplify federated google login work properly on browser but dont work on Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, aws-amplify

The issues are when I am trying to run federated authentication with the help of amplify auth method on the browser it works fine, but when I try to run it on my mobile.

It throws error `No user found` when I try to use `Auth.currentSession()` but the same work on the browser.

tried to search about this type of issue but I found related to `ionic-cordova-google-plugin` not related to AWS Amplify Federated Login Issue.

**Updating the question after closing the question with less debugging information without asking for any information.**

This is issues raised in git hub with respect to my problem.

1. Issue No. 5351 amplify js it's still in open state.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5351

2. Another issue 3537 which is still in Open

These two issues has the same scenario like me, I hope its enough debugging information, **if more required mention comment instead of closing without notification, it's bullying for a beginner not helping**

Comment: have you got any success related to this problem, i am also facing the same issue

Comment: well ya I got the answer to fix it but can't post as the question close. You can vote to reopen so that I can post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the above problem by referring a comment or wrapped around fix.

Link that will take to that comment directly [link to comment](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3537#issuecomment-552197632).

- First read the above comment as it will give you overall idea of what exactly the issue is instead of directly jumping to the solution.
- Once you read the comment you will be little unclear with respect to implementation as he has use capacitor and not every one are using capacitor.

In my implementation I ignore this part as I am not using capacitor.

```
App.addListener('appUrlOpen')
```

- Now lets go to main step where we are fixing this issue, I am using deep links to redirect to my application

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.deeplinks
        .route({
          "/success.html": "success",
          "/logout.html": "logout",
        })
        .subscribe(
          (match: any) => {
            const fragment = JSON.stringify(match).split('"fragment":"')[1];
             // this link can be your any link based on your requirement, 
             // what I am doing it I am passing all the data which I get in my fragments.
             // fragments consists of id_token, stage, code,response type.
             // These need to be passed to Ionic in order for Amplify to run its magic.
            document.location.href = `http://192.168.1.162:8100/#${fragment}`;
          },
          (nomatch) => {
            console.log("Got a deeplink that didn't match", nomatch);
          }
        );
    });
```

I got this idea by referring the issue in which the developer mentioned of sending code and state along with application deep linking URL.

Comment: hello, I have  two question please. How do you launch hostedUi with crafted url or Auth.federatedSignin() methode?  Dou you use PKCE? Because with crafted url pkce doesnt work. And if i use Auth.federatedSignin()  for PKCE , my deeplink is never used.